# PHP close HTTP connection then continue processing?

Tags: php, http

Why is the last line of this function required to make this work? I don't understand what's going on here. It does work though.

```
function close_connection() {
    // if we're using sessions this stops them from hanging on other requests
    session_write_close();
    // get the content length from the buffer (the whole point of the buffer)
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    // close the connection
    header('Connection: close');
    // flush the buffers to the screen
    flush();

    // connection closing doesn't work without this. I don't know why
    echo ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are sent whenever the first byte is output to the browser.
You could also try to use `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: I tried with `ob_end_flush()` before actually. it wasn't doing anything so I removed it. Probably because my buffer was totally empty?

Comment: you could check that by using :
    `$obsize = ob_get_length();`  
and then use that output size in your header Content-Length:   
    `header("Content-Length: $obsize");`

Comment: Can I flush buffers without sending any content?

Comment: Yes, by using `ob_clean()` or `ob_get_clean()`

Comment: If your server compresses output, you need to disable it with header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");